# PLY reduce/reduce conflict

Tags: python, compiler-construction, ply

I am encountering a reduce / reduce conflict that I am unsure how to tackle.

I have the following grammar :

```
   Type -> int 
         | bool
         | void 
         | string 
         | char
         | Identifier

   Expression -> ...
                ...
                | Expression Index
                | Identifier


   VariableDecl -> Type Identifier Initializer Semi
                  | Type LBRAC RBRAC Identifier Initializer Semi

   Index -> LBRAC Expression RBRAC
```

The problem arises when I provide the following snippet to my parser :

array[5] = 5;

where array is an int[].

Following my parser.out I see that the sequence "array[" is being captured as a VariableDecl instead of an expression with a member access operator.

Identifier is used throughout my spec but only appeared as an issue with this specific case.

Answer (score 2):

Either you need to use some mechanism outside of the parser (such as a symbol table) to distinguish between Types and other Identifiers, or you need to avoid forcing the parser to immediately reduce `identifier`. That's a bit of a pain, because it requires a bit of duplication of grammar rules.

Here's one possibility, which might or might not look a lot like your parser. I added a simple assignment statement and a couple of expression operators, to show the pattern (in the actual grammar, there is a `precedence` array to avoid the shift-reduce conflicts in expressions; that's not really relevant to this question).

```
prog -> stmts
stmt -> decl ; 
stmt -> expr ; 
stmt -> assign ;
stmts -> <empty>
stmts -> stmts stmt
assign -> lvalue = expr
decl -> type IDENT init
decl -> TYPE [ ] IDENT array_init
decl -> IDENT [ ] IDENT array_init
type -> TYPE
type -> IDENT
init -> <empty>
array_init -> <empty>
init -> = expr
array_init -> = array_val
array_val -> { }
array_val -> { expr_list }
expr_list -> expr
expr_list -> expr_list , expr
expr -> term
expr -> IDENT
expr -> CHAR
expr -> INT
term -> STRING
term -> index
lvalue -> IDENT 
lvalue -> index 
index -> term [ expr ]
index -> IDENT [ expr ]
expr -> expr + expr
expr -> expr - expr
expr -> expr * expr
expr -> expr / expr
term -> ( expr )
```

Some of the decisions I made there fairly arbitrary (and might be wrong), but it gives an idea, I hope. Basically, the things at the end of the `expr` hierarchy, which might just be terms in a simpler grammar, are divided into several overlapping categories:

- `term`: things other than `IDENT` which can be indexed;
- `lvalue`: things which can be assigned to;
- literals other than `STRING`: just tossed into `expr` because they don't fit into the other categories;
- `IDENT`: handled specially with redundant productions to avoid premature reduction.
  Also, `IDENT` is separated from `type` and handled with a redundant production for the same reason.

Comment: Wouldnt there still be a reduce/reduce conflict with the example you provided? Identifier would still be able to reduce to either Type or Expression

Comment: @WholesomePorridge: Yes, quite right. I redid it using a more general pattern (the one I'd used the first time assumed that you could only index an `IDENT`, not an arbitrary expression.)